# Is there a way to access data from a Nuxt 3 server api route inside of another server route?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, sitemap, nuxtjs3, nitro

I'm working on a Nuxt 3 application where I need to generate a sitemap dynamically from a CMS using the [method described for Nuxt Content](https://content.nuxtjs.org/guide/recipes/sitemap/). I'm using the built in /server/api/ directory to get this data for the rest of the app. My sitemap.xml.js file is in /server/routes/.

I'd like to be able to make $fetch requests from my sitemap file to the apis instead of rewriting all of that code (making the $fetch requests to the CMS again).

##### sitemap.xml.js

```js
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const { auth, posts } = useRuntimeConfig()

//[...]

  const { records: postList } = await $fetch(`${posts}?api_key=${auth}`)

  postList.forEach((post) => {
    if(post.fields.Status){
      sitemap.write({
        url: 'posts/' + post.fields.Slug + '/',
        lastmod: post.lastMod
      })
    }
  })

//[...]

}
```

##### What I would like to do

```js
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {

//[...]

  const { records: postList } = await $fetch('/api/posts')

  postList.forEach((post) => {
    sitemap.write({
      url: 'posts/' + post.fields.Slug + '/',
      lastmod: post.lastMod
    })
  })

//[...]

}
```

My sitemap code all works fine, I just can't get the data from my other server routes. Does anyone know if this is possible/how to do it?